# how to count an equal value of a mobile window IN R?

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
event <- c("2020-03-25","2020-03-24","2020-03-23","2020-03-22","2020-03-21","2020-03-20","2020-03-19","2020-03-18","2020-03-17","2020-03-16","2020-03-15")
P <- c(71,2,0,23.8,0,23.8,0,0,12,69,9)
df <- data.frame(event,P)
```

I wanna count how many times the number 0 appears in the last 5 days, counting from numbers greater than 60.

For example:
P = 71 (25/03/2020)
Number of 0 = 2

My current script is like:

```
df_accumulate <- df %>% 
     arrange(event) %>% 
     # 5 days
     mutate(ACU_5d = slider::slide_dbl(.x = P,.f = ~sum(.x),.before = 5,.after = -1)) %>% # accumulated sum of the previous 5 days 
     mutate(bar_5d = if_else(P>60,ACU_5d,NA_real_)) #If P>60, this column receives the accumulated sum
```

I wanna create another column with a count of zeros in that space of 5 days.
How can I do this in R? Is it possible to apply the count (dplyr) in f on slide_dbl?

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar approach to count number of 0's.

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

df_accumulate  <- df %>% 
  arrange(event) %>% 
  mutate(ACU_5d = slide_dbl(.x = P,.f = ~sum(.x),.before = 5,.after = -1), 
         count_zero_5d = slide_dbl(.x = P,.f = ~sum(.x == 0),.before = 5,.after = -1)) 
  
df_accumulate
```